# How to override a trait's method in abstract class?

Tags: php, abstract-class, traits

I'm stuck into a problem with traits I can't solve on my own.

I have **classes extending** an **abstract class** (in my case these are several controller classes and an abstract class `Controller`, the used framework won't be important here, since this is a general PHP question…) **that uses traits**. I'd like to **override a method** defined in one of the traits. This only works as long as I define the method in my sub-classes but not in my abstract class.

---

So, this one works perfectly:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    use AnyTrait;

    public function anyMethodFromAnyTrait()
    {
        // override AnyTrait::anyMethodFromAnyTrait()
    }
}
```

I also know how to call the `anyMethodFromAnyTrait` method from `AnyTrait` by using `as`.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    use AnyTrait { AnyTrait::anyMethodFromAnyTrait as method }

    public function anyMethodFromAnyTrait()
    {
        // invoke AnyTrait::anyMethodFromAnyTrait()
        $this->method();
    }
}
```

Both work like a charm.

---

But my problem is a bit different.

When using the trait and defining the method in my **abstract class** I am **not able to override** the trait's method.

Assume the following controller class:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function anyAction()
    {
        // let's see what happens…
        $this->anyMethodFromAnyTrait();
    }
}
```

…and the abstract one that's extended by `MyController`:

```
abstract class Controller
{
    use AnyTrait

    public function anyMethodFromAnyTrait()
    {
        // do something different than AnyTrait
    }
}
```

…And this is what's not working at all. Whenever I call `$this->anyMethodFromAnyTrait()` within `MyController` the trait's method as implememented in `AnyTrait` will be invoked. The same named method in my abstract `Controller` will be ignored.

Therefore I only can override a trait's method in a concrete sub-class but not in an abstract class that is extended by that sub-class.

**So the method definitions in traits get a higher priority by PHP than the same method definitions in abstract classes.**

Do you know any workaround for that behaviour?

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior with either PHP 5.5 nor PHP 7? May you please link me to a concrete http://3v4l.org reproduce case?

Comment: Any reason you cannot use `use AnyTrait { AnyTrait::anyMethodFromAnyTrait as method }` in `Controller`?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @llioor I can't remember in detail since it's too long ago. But I'm sure I did not override those traits' methods. Maybe I even implemented a new method whose content I copied from the trait and then changed it to my needs. I really don't rmember, sorry for that.

Comment: I solved it by overriding the trait function. The sub class gives higher priority to trait's function than to super class function so the only way is to override the trait's function.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to use the traits ONLY in the subclasses.
PHP always prefers the trait methods over the "local" ones.

The reason why it works in subclasses is, that the trait method of the superclass is extended, not the trait usage itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This kind of workaround is actually what I want to avoid since I am using that abstract class for some reason as you can imagine. ;-)

Comment: But why use a function of a trait and then overwrite it in the same class?
What do you want to achieve? Or it that function "unwanted" in the trait?

Comment: The function is definately wanted, that's why I'm using the trait. But I want to change the method's behaviour a little bit by adding just a few lines of code to its beginning. Unfortunately this trait is part of the framework I'm using and therefore I can't just change the method itself. … I think I will implement a complete other solution that I don't need to override the trait function for.